# Creating a loop to compare time between dates (oracle SQL)

Tags: oracle, loops

Here is an example of data (I'm just sharing an example of one person to hep illustrate my question):

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | January 1, 2021 |
| 1 | February 1, 2021 |
| 1 | March 1, 2021 |
| 1 | April 1, 2021 |
| 1 | May 1, 2021 |
| 1 | June 1, 2021 |

**ID** = a unique identifier for a person

**DATE** = when that person enrolled in a program

A person can enroll in a program for up to 40 days. After that period is up, they become eligible for enrollment again. However, sometimes (for various administrative purposes) someone may enter an enrollment for someone before they are eligible. I am trying to figure out the best way to flag which enrollments were actually eligible.

So for example, the January enrollment is fine because that was the member's first enrollment (so it should be flagged). However, their February enrollment did not occur after 40 days of the prior eligible enrollment (from January), and it should not be flagged. The March enrollment did occur more than 40 days after the eligible January enrollment, so it should be flagged. The April enrollment did not occur after 40 days of the prior eligible enrollment (March) and so it should not be flagged......

I suspect I need to create some sort of loop (I would know how to do this in other programming languages but not SQL. My thinking is along the lines of:

1. January is the first enrollment so it should be flagged and move to the next row (January stored as the date reference).
2. February did not occur more than 40 days after the January reference so it should not be flagged, move to the next row (January still the reference).
3. March did occur more than 40 days after the January reference so it should be flagged, move to the next row (March is now the reference)

.....

Can anyone help me figure out how I could accomplish this?

Comment: What is your Oracle version? If you don't know, run `select banner from v$version` and tell us what it reports - the row that looks like `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production` (that's what my system reports when I run that query). My version is 12.2.0.1.0. What is yours?

Comment: _" suspect I need to create some sort of loop (I would know how to do this in other programming languages"_  An important thing you need to keep in mind is that those "other languages" are all _procedural_.  You code _how_ to do something, step-by-step.  But SQL (not just oracle) is a _descriptive_ language.  You code _what_ you want and let the database figure out _how_.  Also, SQL is working with _sets_.  It is not a row-by-row language.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brief demo using `match_recognize` (which has been available since Oracle 12.1). It takes some time to learn it if you don't know it already; if you are familiar with analytic functions and with regular expressions (for strings), the learning will be easier.

First some test data (creating a small table):

```
create table enrolments (id, enrolment_date) as
  select 1, date '2021-01-01' from dual union all
  select 1, date '2021-02-01' from dual union all
  select 1, date '2021-03-01' from dual union all
  select 1, date '2021-04-01' from dual union all
  select 1, date '2021-05-01' from dual union all
  select 1, date '2021-06-01' from dual union all
  select 8, date '2021-01-05' from dual union all
  select 8, date '2021-03-10' from dual union all
  select 8, date '2021-03-15' from dual union all
  select 8, date '2021-04-10' from dual
;
```

A few notes here - `DATE` is a reserved keyword, so it can't be a column name (I hope it isn't in your real-life data); in my example the date column is `date` data type (and I hope it is in your real-life data too, rather than being string data type); and I used the **date literal** syntax to insert dates.

Then the query and output (and a command to change date formatting in the output to match yours):

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'fmMonth dd, yyyy';

select id, enrolment_date, flag
from   enrolments
match_recognize(
  partition by id
  order     by enrolment_date
  measures  nullif(classifier(), 'NOT_ELIGIBLE') as flag
  all rows per match
  pattern   ( ELIGIBLE NOT_ELIGIBLE* )
  define    NOT_ELIGIBLE as enrolment_date < ELIGIBLE.enrolment_date + 40
);

ID  ENROLMENT_DATE     FLAG           
--  -----------------  -----------
 1  January 1, 2021    ELIGIBLE       
 1  February 1, 2021                  
 1  March 1, 2021      ELIGIBLE       
 1  April 1, 2021                     
 1  May 1, 2021        ELIGIBLE       
 1  June 1, 2021                      
 8  January 5, 2021    ELIGIBLE       
 8  March 10, 2021     ELIGIBLE       
 8  March 15, 2021                    
 8  April 10, 2021
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to have worked perfectly! :)

And yes, the data I shared here is not real and my columns have "real" names, they just wouldn't be super meaningful here so I just labeled them as ID and DATE (even though as you say DATE cannot be a column name).